# Check if Date X is after Date Y with JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using the jodatime `DateTime` variable. I'd like to check if DateTime 'x' is after DateTime 'y'. The isAfter function only accepts a `long` parameter, not a `DateTime`, which I find very odd. Whats the best way to compare two `DateTime`s?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a Method `boolean isAfter(ReadableInstant instant)` in ReadableInstant, so as DateTime implements ReadableInstant it should accept a DateTime as well.

Comment: I saw that overload but ignored it because I didn't know I could pass in a `DateTime` when it was expecting a `ReadableInstant`. Thanks!

Comment: @Teifi If this answered your question you should consider accepting.

Comment: The above answer is one of the best methods to use

Comment: [The docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isAfter(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)) for `isAfter` say "Is this instant after the instant passed in comparing solely by millisecond." What do they mean "solely by millisecond"? They just mean the timezone is disregarded, right?

Answer (score 3):

**Method isAfter Description**

```
public boolean isAfter(ReadableInstant instant)

    Is this instant after the instant passed in comparing solely by millisecond.

    Specified by:
        isAfter in interface ReadableInstant

    Parameters:
        instant - an instant to check against, null means now 
    Returns:
        true if the instant is after the instant passed in
```

It takes `ReadableInstant` as argument so `DateTime` can also be passed as clear from `DateTime Hierarchy`

```
Class DateTime

java.lang.Object
  extended by org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant
      extended by org.joda.time.base.AbstractDateTime
          extended by org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime
              extended by org.joda.time.DateTime

All Implemented Interfaces:
    Serializable, Comparable<ReadableInstant>, ReadableDateTime, ReadableInstant
```

Above details is been taken from [joda api docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: When [the docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isAfter(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)) say "comparing solely by millisecond," what do they mean "solely by millisecond"? They just mean the timezone is disregarded, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.err.println(new DateTime().isAfter(new DateTime().plusDays(1)));
}
```

works for me

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `getMillis()` method inherited from `BaseDateTime` that gives you a `long` value representing the dates, you can compare the two `long` values to determine which is before, and by how much.

Comment: As stated, if you want to know the exact difference between the two DateTime objects for additional output later on in the code.